# Tricks to avoid scrolling on mobile app?

Tags: scrolling

I am asked by a client to add extra text/list-based content to the dashboard screen of an existing app. The most strait forward way to do this would be to simply add the text underneath what's currently showing in the dashboard, but this will require most users to scroll down in order to see it, which is not desirable.

Can anyone recommend other methods for doing this in which the content would still be accessible for the user, but scrolling won't be required in order to see it?

Comment: Why is scrolling not desirable? Though the more important question here is what value the additional text provides to the user in the dashboard.

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Does the text relate in any way to the information already shown in the dashboard? Are there other lists/text fields in the dashboard currently and how do they behave?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or wireframe for the existing dashboard, and some detail around what sort of additional list-based content you're trying to add (is it 2 items? 10? 100? fixed? variable).  It's hard to provide suggestions without a sense of the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Expanding panel from one of the edges (left, right or bottom preferable to top)
- Swipe left or right
- Long-press on a piece of information
- Expandable tab in the page, which pushes something out the way
- Dynamically load the content into a "content space" on the push of a button
- Slideshow it with other information (I think this is a bad idea)
- Fade out something unimportant and then fade this in

Really, though, scrolling is probably the most intuitive way.